# setup.py script breaks with latest version of virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools

I have a package that I install via `python setup.py install`, that's been working fine until I tried to install it this morning in a fresh machine.

On previous machines, `virtualenv` comes with `setuptools==2.0.2`, but on my new machine it's now at `setuptools==3.6`.

Now, when I install the package using `setup.py install`, I can't import the package or run the scripts included in it.

Here's the package's `setup.py` file:

```
__version__ = '1.0.2'


import sys
try:
    from setuptools import setup
    print 'Loaded setuptools'
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
    print 'Loaded distutils.core'


PACKAGE_NAME = 'google-taskqueue-client'
INSTALL_REQUIRES = ['google-apputils==0.1',
                    'google-api-python-client',
                    'httplib2',
                    'oauth2',
                    'python-gflags']
setup(name=PACKAGE_NAME,
      version=__version__,
      description='Google TaskQueue API command-line tool and utils',
      author='Google Inc.',
      author_email='google-appengine@googlegroups.com',
      url='http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/pull/overview.html',
      install_requires=INSTALL_REQUIRES,
      packages=['gtaskqueue'],
      scripts=['gtaskqueue/gtaskqueue', 'gtaskqueue/gtaskqueue_puller',
               'gtaskqueue/gen_appengine_access_token'],
      license='Apache 2.0',
      keywords='google taskqueue api client',
      classifiers=['Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
                   'Intended Audience :: Developers',
                   'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
                   'Operating System :: POSIX',
                   'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP'])
```

The install itself runs fine, but I can't use the modules of the package.
Here's the error thrown when trying one of the scripts listed:

```
$ which gtaskqueue
/Users/john/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/gtaskqueue
$ gtaskueue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/john/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/gtaskqueue", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('google-taskqueue-client==1.0.2', 'gtaskqueue')
  File "/Users/john/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 534, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/Users/john/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1441, in run_script
    exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/Users/john/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google_taskqueue_client-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/gtaskqueue", line 25, in <module>

ImportError: No module named gtaskqueue
```

**EDIT:**

All dependencies installed fine as well (I had to update `'google-apputils==0.1'` requirement to the latest version)

```
>>> import google.apputils
>>> import httplib2
>>> import oauth2
>>> import gflags
>>> import oauth2client
>>> import gtaskqueue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gtaskqueue
```

**EDIT 2:**

[Here's the full stacktrace of the `setup.py install` process.](https://www.refheap.com/85712)

Comment: have you tried `pip install gtaskqueue`?

Comment: So, the install went without a hitch?

Comment: Yes, install 'worked' fine. Just can't use/import any of the modules of the package.

Comment: This is strange, I cant even get the install to work properly. Files missing everywhere.

Comment: Are you sure a dependency hasn't change and thus caused upstream that's actually now broken? I note you don't pin everything you depend on.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the dependencies.. Updated the OP verifying the dependencies can be used normally.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac you mean install the same package as I'm installing? It's my own (public) mirror, so not sure what you're trying to install.